# How to change the expire cache time in gradle

Tags: gradle, caching

For some reason I can't access the nexus repository I am normally using. 
As drawback when I run any gradle task of my project, I have the error that the nexus registered is not reachable.

Since all my libraries are present in my cache, there should not be any issue. 
But gradle blocks me by trying to refresh the libraries.

Does somebody knows how I can change this setting and set a bigger expire date, or if any workaround exists ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

For Gradle Kotlin DSL users:

```
tasks.register<Copy>("cacheToMavenLocal") {
    from(file(gradle.gradleUserHomeDir.parent + "/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1"))
    into(repositories.mavenLocal().url)
    eachFile {
        val parts = path.split('/')
        path = (parts[0] + '/' + parts[1]).replace('.', '/') + '/' + parts[2] + '/' + parts[4]
    }
    includeEmptyDirs = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some googlings, a workaround could be to use a maven local repository and to copy the gradle cache into this new maven local repo.

This can be done using this gradle task :

```
task cacheToMavenLocal(type: Copy) {
  from new File(gradle.gradleUserHomeDir, 'caches/modules-2/files-2.1')
  into repositories.mavenLocal().url
  eachFile {
    List<String> parts = it.path.split('/')
    it.path = (parts[0]+ '/' + parts[1]).replace('.','/') + '/' + parts[2] + '/' + parts[4]
  }
  includeEmptyDirs false
}
```

inspiration link : https://discuss.gradle.org/t/need-a-gradle-task-to-copy-all-dependencies-to-a-local-maven-repo/13397/14